# Cut the last 2 characters of cmd.exe script response

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I want to write a script that esentially pings another computer and gets average as number only. Right now I have a script that gets average ping as needed and shows it, but it has 'ms' prefix and I want to get rid of it. I can't seem to find `cut` equivalent (alright, I did found, but I can't make my existing script and it work together) that is already in Windows (it should be in cmd.exe by default).

My script:

```
FOR /F "usebackq skip=11 tokens=6 delims== " %i IN (`ping host2.internal`) DO @echo %i
```

I get: `197ms`, but I need it to look like: `197`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `DO` part with

```
DO @set FOO=%i & echo %FOO:~0,-3%
```

This assigns the value of `%i` to a temporary variable `FOO` so that you can then use the substring extraction capability of the shell (`SET /?` for explanation). I am shaving off three characters instead of two because `%i` includes a trailing space.

Comment: Thanks! `FOR /F "usebackq skip=11 tokens=6 delims== " %i IN (\`ping host2.internal\`) DO @set FOO=%i & echo %FOO:~0,-4%` worked nicely (leaving it ~0,-3 resulted in `197m`)

Comment: (Tested on Windows 7) I believe you need to change `echo %FOO:~0,-3%` to `echo %FOO:~0,-2%` as the -4 means take the string from position 0 to 4 in from the end.  Both -3 and -4 misbehaved here on results longer than 3 digits and shorter than 3 digits.

Comment: @JimR: On my machine `-3` was correct. There are obviously some small differences, not sure where they are coming from.

Comment: @Jon I've realised that there is problem that FOO gets assigned and it is stored for later, is there any way to flush `FOO` after `echo`? If I execute this script to host1, then try to ping host2 the first time there will be shown result of host1. It's correct on the latter executions.

Comment: @the_lay: `SETLOCAL` at the beginning of the script. Check out `SETLOCAL /?` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This works here in Win 8: the -4 is required for occasions where IPV6 is also in force.

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims==<ms" %i IN ('ping -4 www.google.com ^|find "Reply from"') DO @echo %i
```